# Getting AWS Data Transfer charges to regions outside my servers region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My ec2 instance is getting charged for data transfer from almost every available AWS region (Tokyo, Seoul, Singapore, Paris, London, Germany, Ireland, Ohio, Oregon, Sydney, Canada Central, Sao Paulo, Cloud Front, INCLUDING AWS GovCloud (US)). our 99.99% users are from India. As per recommendations of AWS representative have checked no other script are running on our instance and have changed rules for security group inbound rule having only SSH connection on port 22 to static IP. But still, there is data transfer of almost 600GB+. And the documentation for security group doesn't help much is there any other way to stop this data transfer?

Please note that EC2 instance runs the php code and java api tomcat7 service & RDS is on other instance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, your question looks like you mention data transfer to other EC2 instances in another region. Perhaps you meant traffic to internet users in other regions?

Second, according to [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) you'll be billed for Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet whichever region you are and regardless whether the endpoint is in internet or AWS region. So, even if you have users in Mumbai you'll be billed for outbound traffic anyway.

Third, if you want to block transfer on country basis use CDN with proper capability, e.g. CloudFlare.

Please elaborate your question if you meant something else.